# Read string at current cursor position instead of in minibuffer

Tags: input-method, perl

I am trying to simplify user input of Pod formatting sequences in `cperl-mode`. For example, if you type `C<hello>`, `C<>` is a Pod formatting sequence for entering code, similar to the use of backticks in Markdown.

The idea is that the user should only have to type `C<` and then Emacs will ask for the code text and add the ending `>` followed by as space automatically. Here is an example; for simplicity I have not added the function to `cperl-mode-hook` yet, so you can test this by doing `emacs -Q -l init.el`, where `init.el` is:

```el
(defun my-perl-pod-format-start ()
  "Simplify entering of Pod formatting sequences."
  (interactive)
  (let ((char (preceding-char)))
    (insert "<")
    (when (or
           (char-equal char ?C)
           (char-equal char ?I)
           (char-equal char ?B))
      (insert (read-string "Pod formatting code: "))
      (insert "> "))))

(global-set-key (kbd "<") #'my-perl-pod-format-start))
```

This seems to work fine, but there is at least one drawback: the flow of writing is interrupted, since as soon as the user type the `<` the focus is moved to the minibuffer. So I wondered, is it possible to do this input (similar to `read-string`) at the current cursor position (for example like in `auto-complete-mode`) instead of in the minibuffer?

Comment: See function `completion-at-point`.

Comment: Sounds like a job for a yasnippet.